# Just get the type of Powershell Object [collection?] (not the methods etc) (also: what's going on here?)

Tags: powershell

I am setting the variable 'a' like this:

```
$a=dir -recurse c:\temp
```

If I now examine this object with 'get-member' like this:

```
$a|get-member
```

I get back the type, but also all the methods and other properties like this:

```
   TypeName: System.IO.FileInfo

Name                      MemberType     Definition                                                                                            
----                      ----------     ----------                                                                                            
Mode                      CodeProperty   System.String Mode{get=Mode;}                                                                         
AppendText                Method         System.IO.StreamWriter AppendText()                                                                   
CopyTo                    Method         System.IO.FileInfo CopyTo(string destFileName), System.IO.FileInfo CopyTo(string destFileName, bool...
[...]
```

Which is nice; but sometimes I just want to get hold of the type (I'll look up whatever it does afterwards).

So I tried this:

```
$a|get-member|select-object -Property typename
```

The output suprised me initially: because what you get back is the typename for each individual item in the collection- and the types (although clearly related) are not identical:

```
TypeName
--------
System.IO.DirectoryInfo
System.IO.DirectoryInfo
System.IO.DirectoryInfo
[...]
System.IO.FileInfo
[...]
```

Then I thought about this; and it sort of made sense - this is a collection of Objects that I'm piping through the Object-Pipeline; but then it made me think:

1. What was 'Get-Member' actually telling me previously ? When it said the type was 'System.IO.FileInfo' - but actually the collection contains a mixture of object types ?
2. Whatever it is 'Get-Member' is displaying - how do I get at that *exact* thing ?

I can almost (sort-of, but actually its just wrong) get what I thought I was initially after with this:

```
$a|get-member|select-object -Property typename -first 1
```

But this just peeks at the 'first' object; and in fact gives me a different answer to what 'Get-Member' output for me.

So what is the 'TypeName' that 'Get-Member' is showing- and where is that stored ?

Is the value of 'dir' (Get-ChildItem against a filepath) simply a collection of objects, or is it a parent object (with its own set of 'scalar' properties) and a single property referencing a collection of associated objects ?

Comment: Thanks - but that still iterates over all the items within the collection - rather than giving the same information that 'get-member' does at the top of its report?

Comment: `$a | % GetType | Select -Unique`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a lot of questions in one, let's see if we can make some sense of this.

The `TypeName` that `Get-Member` displays *for each distinct type of object* (we'll get back to that), comes from a hidden property that all objects in PowerShell carry, called `pstypenames`:

```
PS C:\> $something = 1
PS C:\> $something.pstypenames
System.Int32
System.ValueType
System.Object
PS C:\>
```

So, `pstypenames` is an ordered list of all the types in that objects type hierarchy. If we change the value of `pstypenames`, you'll see that reflected in the output from `Get-Member`:

```
PS C:\> $something.pstypenames.Insert(0,"MonoJohnny.CustomTypeName")
PS C:\> Get-Member -InputObject $something


   TypeName: MonoJohnny.CustomTypeName

Name        MemberType Definition
----        ---------- ----------
...
```

So, if you want the `TypeName` for an object, as displayed by `Get-Member`, you can always do:

```
$something.pstypenames[0]
```

As shown above, this value can be manipulated, so if you want the **true type** of an object at runtime, use the `GetType()` method:

```
$something.GetType().FullName
```

---

The reason that `Get-Member` only shows you the entire list of properties for a `System.IO.FileInfo` object *once* is that it (rightly so) assumes that all other objects of type `System.IO.FileInfo` will have the exact same members - no need to duplicate that output.

I you have multiple distinct types in a collection and pipe those to `Get-Member`, it'll only show you the members for the *first* object it encounters with a unique type name (remember, the value of `pstypenames[0]`). This is the case when you pipe `Get-ChildItem` to `Get-Member`, since `Get-ChildItem` on the filesystem provider only returns two different types of objects - `FileInfo` objects and `DirectoryInfo` objects.

---

For builtin types this is totally fine, but with custom objects that you create in PowerShell, this can be quite annoying.

Consider the following example:

```
PS C:\> $Object1 = New-Object psobject -Property @{ Prop1 = 1 }
PS C:\> $Object2 = New-Object psobject -Property @{ Prop2 = 2 }
```

Now, `$Object1` and `$Object2` are clearly 2 different kinds of objects - they have different property names. But what happens when we pipe them to `Get-Member` in the same pipeline:

```
PS C:\> $Object1,$Object2 |Get-Member


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
Prop1       NoteProperty System.Int32 Prop1=1
```

Since the underlying *type* of both objects are `System.Management.Automation.PSObject`, the value of `pstypenames` is also the same for both, and `Get-Member` can't distinguish between the two.

Now, all of a sudden, the ability to manipulate `pstypenames` without actually fiddling with the type system comes in handy:

```
PS C:\> $Object1.pstypenames.Insert(0,"ObjectType1")
PS C:\> $Object2.pstypenames.Insert(0,"ObjectType2")
PS C:\> $Object1,$Object2 |Get-Member


   TypeName: ObjectType1

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
Prop1       NoteProperty System.Int32 Prop1=1


   TypeName: ObjectType2

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
Prop2       NoteProperty System.Int32 Prop2=2
```

Sweet!

---

You can also inject a custom type name during object creation by specifying `PSTypeName` as a string property:

```
PS C:\> $Object1 = New-Object psobject -Property @{ Prop1 = 1; PSTypeName = 'ObjectType1' }
PS C:\> $Object2 = New-Object psobject -Property @{ Prop2 = 2; PSTypeName = 'ObjectType2' }
```

Comment: Excellent ! Thanks very much for this much detail !

Comment: @monojohnny Happy to help. If you feel I left some of your questions unanswered, feel free to post another.

Comment: Oh - I'm sure I have will have plenty more questions ! (It seems that everything is much more complicated that it first looked !) Thanks again !